# Button ibaction is not getting called in tableview

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, delegates, swift-protocols

So i have set up a protocol so that I can use the buttons in my tableviewcontroller, but it's not working. I know for a fact I set the protocol up right (cuz the print statements get called in it when i tried it out), but the function is not being called in the tableviewcontroller. Here is some code:

```
protocol CommentCellDelegate
{
    func reply(index: Int)
}

class CommentCell: UITableViewCell
{
    var delegate: CommentCellDelegate?
    var index: IndexPath?
    
    //Other outlets omitted for brevity
    @IBOutlet var replyButton: UIButton!
    
    override func awakeFromNib()
    {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        // Initialization code
    }

    @IBAction func reply(_ sender: Any)
    {
        delegate?.reply(index: index!.row)
    }
}
```

```
extension commentsTableViewController: CommentCellDelegate
{
    func reply(index: Int)
    {
        print("button tpapped")
        let comment = comments[index]
        globalComment = comment
        print(globalComment.comment!)
        self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "commentVC", sender: self)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Inside `cellForRowAt` make sure to set the delegate

```
let cell = ........
cell.delegate = self
```